# apt-get install build-essential

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vps

I am writing bash script for vps server. I got this problem:
I need to install the `build-essential` package by script.

Command using in script:

```bash
eval 'apt-get install build-essential'
```

I coped with the problem (yes / no), found the `-y` switch for `apt-get`.

```bash
eval 'apt-get -y install build-essential'
```

But how to get around the second problem?:

```
(Enter the items or ranges you want to select, separated by spaces.)

Which services should be restarted?
```

I don't have to choose anything. A simple press of Enter would solve the problem!

So, any

```bash
echo, echo "\r", yes | apt-get -y install build-essential
```

does not working and my ideas are over!

Comment: [Passing default answers to apt-get package install questions?](https://serverfault.com/q/407317/278025)

Comment: 'eval' is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If eval is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this problem! The reboot service selection menu pops up on Ubuntu 22.04. I installed 20.04 and
and there is no menu. Might be useful for someone!